# When to Update the ViewModel from Database [Caching ViewModel]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, caching, model

Okay so I will try to make things short and straightforward.

As you might know, I have my Database using EntityFramework, then I have my Database Model classes that gets initialized by Database, and then I have my View Models where I have the fields for each html control, in the last I have my Controller with a specific ViewModel instance.

My question is, the View Model is created **once** on my controller (any action) request, on the other times I always check if it is null, and if it's null then I rebuild the View Model fetching the data from the database using my Database Model classes, this is the right thing to do right? So I can get a improvement on Performance.. right? since I am reusing the View Model and not creating it every time...?

The problem comes when some field gets updated by the administrator in the Backoffice.
How can I overcome this? I see the following options:

> 1) Set a lifetime (minutes/hours) on my ViewModel object inside the
>   controller (once expired I set it to null).
>
> 2) I try to handle a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> key combination and I set the ViewModel
>   object inside the controller to null.
>
> 3) I rebuild the ViewModel every http request to the controller (this
>   is so bad...)
>
> 4) I use Http Session of each Client, when the backoffice updates a
>   field, each Http Session on my ASP.NET WebApplication get's triggered
>   with some flag to set the View Model object to null (I don't even know
>   if this is possible, but it seems the most elegant way, right?

Here is an example of what I am doing at the moment, but in some cases, I might need to recreate the ViewModel (because database for View fields changed):

```
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IndexViewModel indexModel;

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model, string lang = "en")
        {
            indexModel = model;
            if (indexModel == null)
                indexModel = new IndexViewModel();

            indexModel.SelectedLanguage = lang;

            return View(indexModel);
        }

       //more actions..
}
```

Looking forward to hear all your responses and feedback,
This a question primarly focused on Performance and CPU Time optimization, I want my clients to have a fresh, clean and fast experience using my website.

Thank you!

EDIT: Question edited with more info.

Comment: What do you mean _on the other times I always check if it is null_? Are you storing you view model in `Session` (and why?). And what makes you think that initializing your view model on each request is bad?

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke thank for your reply. I mean I do something like checking the model is null, in that case, I construct the model again, you get it? I am not storing the model anyway, the model just keeps going from controller-view to view-controller, I receive the model in my action method parameters. I say that initializing my view model is bad because I will use CPU in cases that data didn't changed at all... so I could use the same fields already existing in the model view object...

Comment: Where and when are you checking if its `null`? (sorry, but your question is not making sense)

Comment: My understanding is that you are trying to keep your view model up to date, but you don't want to query a database on every http request coming to a controller. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I am sorry @StephenMuecke, I just add now more info on my question, just to make things more clear. yeah yeah that's right @AlexeyAndrushkevich! you got it!

Comment: Are you really making a GET call to that method and passing every property of your `IndexViewModel` in the url? You `model` parameter will be initialized (but not `null`). But `indexModel` will always be `null` when the method is first called, and all your doing is setting it to `model`. The first 3 lines of your method make no sense.

Comment: It makes sense, if it's the first time accessing the Index action the object model will be null that's why I initialize it, in other cases it won't be null and I will use it, do you understand? And yes this is a GET call, not post neither put. So you are right, on the first call indexModel will be null, but not on the following calls to the same method. I think I got what you mean, you are saying that I only get my model with all the fields with value in POST actions right? So I ask you another question, how can I sent the model all filled to a GET action? just on querystring right?

Comment: Please make me a proper answer how to cache my View Model and how to trigger the update to it. Using any thing you might wonder useful, Session, Cookies, wtv... I will be glad to accept  your knowledge as an answer and maybe help someone in the future, this is helpful I think, there are View Models with many fields and it just CPU consuming doing the same task every time without any reason to do it, don't you agree? Thank you again @StephenMuecke!

Comment: @DarkLink, I wouldn't do that this way. If you want to store the state of your view model between requests to your controller you better save it to the `Cache` object and set up an expiration policy for it. Then you could just check if the object is available in cache and if not initialize it and get it updated from a database.

Comment: You would need to include values of all properties of you model in the url. But that really makes no sense and its not clear what your trying to do with this code. The web is stateless. When you make a request, a new instance of you controller is created and the value of `indexModel` will always be `null`. If you have not passed values of you model in the url, then `model` is just a new instance of `IndexViewModel`. SO you can delete the 1st 3 line of code and just use `model.SelectedLanguage = lang; return View(model);`

Comment: Okay thank you @StephenMuecke, that explanation makes sense to me. So in Web Applications it's not a good practice to cache models, I get that. But for performance goals I can always use Cache object and set the model there as Alexey Andrushkevich suggested, I think I will try that approach, and see if using cache object outweights the performance cost of creating the whole view model...

Comment: In a few cases it may make sense to cache models if that data is unlikely to change (for example you may have a collection of product categories that get assigned to a product and those categories will rarely change), but generally its best to call you database to get the data model and build your view model from it. Databases are designed for just that purpose and are blindingly fast at doing it assuming you have set up you database correctly.

Comment: I get what you mean @StephenMuecke it makes sense, and I total agree with you. But there are some cases where the data is most likely to not change (like you said), that's why I can cache it to increase load speed :)
Thank you again for your help, like Alexey you helped me on this subject I had some questions about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ASP.NET MVC controllers are being instantiated on every request. That means that your `indexModel` variable will always be `null` on every request. The web is stateless so you have few options to store the information between requests.

**Client Side**

- Cookie
- Hidden Fields

**Server Side**

- Database or other storage
- Session
- Cache

As far as I understood you use some database and just want to prevent queries being sent to a database on every request to achieve a better performance. One of the option is to use `System.Web.Caching.Cache` object. You can then write something like that.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(string lang = "en")
    {
        IndexViewModel indexViewModel;
        if (HttpContext.Cache["IndexViewModel"]!=null) 
        {
            indexViewModel = HttpContext.Cache["IndexViewModel"];
        }
        else 
        {
            // get your index view model from database by calling some service or repository
            indexViewModel = DatabaseService.GetIndexViewModelFromDatabase();
            // once we got the view model from a database we store it to cache and set it up so that it gets expired in 1 minute
            HttpContext.Cache.Insert("IndexViewModel", indexViewModel, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }

        indexViewModel.SelectedLanguage = lang;

        return View(indexModel);
    }

   [HttpPost]
   [Authorize(Roles="Backoffice")]
   public ActionResult ResetCache(string cacheKey)
   {
       if (HttpContext.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
           HttpContext.Cache.Remove(cacheKey);
   }
   //more actions..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Alexey! I was looking for this, it really helps me, can you just tell me one thing? and maybe edit your answer with your answer about this? The question is: "Can the server, I mean, a User with a specific Role (backoffice) call a specific action in the Controller that triggers all the Client's Cache to be set as null ? So I don't need to wait for the expire and the data is immediatly refreshed after the next check on the model object? thank you!

Comment: Yeah that's right, I know that's the way to do it, my question is, will that remove the cache for the logged user right? not everyone browsing the website using cache at that moment right? Maybe that's too stupid to ask and even not possible... but to let you understand, I would like to trigger this operation (resetcache) to everyone browsing on that specific moment...

Comment: @DarkLink, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) one instance of the `Cache` is created per application domain. That means it's common for all your users so if you put or remove something to/from cache this will affect all your users. If your viewmodel supposed to contain some user-specific information you can change the key "IndexViewModel" to let's say "IndexViewModel_xx" where xx is the unique ID or email of currently logged in user. This will make it possible to reset cache or setup it for every user individually.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexeyAndrushkevich ! That's exactly what I am looking for! :)